# How do I distribute elements in an expression?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, distribution

Given an expression:

```
(A OR B) AND (C OR D) AND (X OR Y OR Z)
```

I need to distribute and generate combinations `ACX`, `ACY`, `ACZ`, `ADX`, `ADY`, `ADZ`, `BCX`, `BCY`, `BCZ`, `BDX`, `BDY` and `BDZ`. We have a UI which is used by users to generate the above expression. In backend we need to generate the different combinations for easier matching against a set of elements like ACX, ACY, etc.

The number of groups with ANDs are not fixed and elements within each AND group vary in size too.

What are thoughts on how to get this done? I am trying to write it with recursion and looking to see if others have smarter answers or if a library exists.

Comment: What do you mean by `AND` and `OR`? Ruby does not have such expressions. Do you mean logical `and` and `or`? If you mean that, then it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks @sawa, I didn't mean logical connectives for any language - just a format to represent a criteria.

Comment: Accepting @the-Tin-Man's answer below for the completeness. For people who are interested in the dynamic version of the solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582481/creating-permutations-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-ruby. Specifically the code block                 head, *rest = a      head.product(*rest)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to produce Cartesian product of arrays in depth-first order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621268/algorithm-to-produce-cartesian-product-of-arrays-in-depth-first-order)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
AB = %w[A B]
CD = %w[C D]
XYZ = %w[X Y Z]

AB.product(CD, XYZ).join(&:map)
```

Which returns an array like:

```
[
  "ACX",
  "ACY",
  "ACZ",
  "ADX",
  "ADY",
  "ADZ",
  "BCX",
  "BCY",
  "BCZ",
  "BDX",
  "BDY",
  "BDZ"
]
```

Ruby's [Array.product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-product) documentation says:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.product(other_ary, ...)                -> new_ary
  ary.product(other_ary, ...) { |p| block }  -> ary


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns an array of all combinations of elements from all arrays. The length of
the returned array is the product of the length of self and the argument
arrays. If given a block, product will yield all combinations and
return self instead.

  [1,2,3].product([4,5])     #=> [[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[3,4],[3,5]]
  [1,2].product([1,2])       #=> [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]
  [1,2].product([3,4],[5,6]) #=> [[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],
                             #    [2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,4,5],[2,4,6]]
  [1,2].product()            #=> [[1],[2]]
  [1,2].product([])          #=> []
```

Of particular interest to your question is the third example.

Comment: OMG! You copied the whole documentation here!! :) I only given him the link. Providing link is the good idea,which helps OP to look around other methods too. :))

Comment: Providing the link only is worthless *when* it breaks. I provided both a link and the pertinent part, which is what we're supposed to do.

Comment: The link has gone down in the past for various reasons, and eventually returned. It's more stable than it was in the past, but, according to common consensus on SO, we shouldn't use only a link, but reference the immediate content. I'm walking as SO likes. "[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)"

Comment: `AB.product(CD, XYZ).join(&:map)` is giving `"ACXACYACZADXADYADZBCXBCYBCZBDXBDYBDZ"`. Thus change `AB.product(CD, XYZ).join(&:map)` to `AB.product(CD, XYZ).map(&:join)`. People without looking into that keep supporting you. Very strange :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. The two got transposed as I was copying from IRB to my editor for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete approach,but I will move this way slowly using [`Array#product`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-product). Give me some moment.

```
a1 = ['A','B']
a2 = ['C','D'] 
a3 = ['X','Y','Z']

a1.product(a2).product(a3)
# => [[["A", "C"], "X"],
#     [["A", "C"], "Y"],
#     [["A", "C"], "Z"],
#     [["A", "D"], "X"],
#     [["A", "D"], "Y"],
#     [["A", "D"], "Z"],
#     [["B", "C"], "X"],
#     [["B", "C"], "Y"],
#     [["B", "C"], "Z"],
#     [["B", "D"], "X"],
#     [["B", "D"], "Y"],
#     [["B", "D"], "Z"]]
```

Here is the complete solution(I used `Array` as a data-structure to keep all the resultant combinations as you asked):

```
a1.product(a2).map(&:join).product(a3).map(&:join)
# => ["ACX",
#     "ACY",
#     "ACZ",
#     "ADX",
#     "ADY",
#     "ADZ",
#     "BCX",
#     "BCY",
#     "BCZ",
#     "BDX",
#     "BDY",
#     "BDZ"]
```

More simplest way is :

```
a1.product(a2,a3).map(&:join)
# => ["ACX",
#     "ACY",
#     "ACZ",
#     "ADX",
#     "ADY",
#     "ADZ",
#     "BCX",
#     "BCY",
#     "BCZ",
#     "BDX",
#     "BDY",
#     "BDZ"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint around Array.product, I am new to Ruby so wasnt aware. Definitely makes the solution elegant. One question about your solution - how do we handle varying number of arrays. Your sample shows 3 but if we had 5 or 10, for example?

Comment: For simplicity I used that one in my example. You could use also - `a1.product(a2,a3,a4,so on)` also. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this in the general case with a recursive descent parser:

```
def expression(stream)
  ret = primary(stream);
  while stream.length > 0 && stream[0] != ")"
    token = stream.shift
    if token == "AND"
      ret = ret.product(primary(stream)).map(&:join)
    elsif token == "OR"
      ret += primary(stream);
    elsif token == "("
      raise "unexpected ("
    end
  end
  return ret
end

def primary(stream) 
  if stream[0] == "("
    stream.shift
    ret = expression(stream)
    raise ") expected" unless stream.shift == ")"
  elsif stream[0] == ")"
    raise "unexpected )"
  else
    ret = [ stream.shift ];
  end
  return ret
end

def parse(str)
  return expression(str.scan(/\)|\(|\w+/))
end

parse('(A OR B) AND (C OR D) AND (X OR Y OR Z)')

=> ["ACX", "ACY", "ACZ", "ADX", "ADY", "ADZ", 
    "BCX", "BCY", "BCZ", "BDX", "BDY", "BDZ"]
```

Answer (score -3):

If you mean by `AND` and `OR` as logical connectives `and` and `or`, then that is impossible.
The expression `(A OR B) AND (C OR D) AND (X OR Y OR Z)` has a certain single value. You cannot get inside of it.

Comment: Thanks sawa, I didn't mean logical connectives for any language - just a format to represent a criteria.

Comment: Formal representation of what?